# PyCharm - remove green lines which appeared upon inserting language reference

Tags: html, django, pycharm

I'm working with django in PyCharm and these green lines are really annoying me.

[image: PyCharm green lines]

They appeared when I inserted some language reference (I can't recall which one exactly...) and I don't know how to turn it off.

I tried editing some PyCharm settings but to no avail...

On the below picture I tried turning all inspections off, but it didn't work.

[image: PyCharm settings]

What is this sorcery and how do I brake it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realized that I needed to turn off Language **injections**.

To make sure that they **all** disappear, you should uncheck all of these:

[image: PyCharm Language injections]

In my case, I had to turn off xml:head, xml:div and xml:script.

You can uncheck one by one to see if which one it is exactly.

Cheers :)